# Trim large lines in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a text file, which is of a structure:

```
attribute:: some_very_long_line
```

this was created with findstr from a bigger txt file, but i need to save only the some_very_long_line part

in a happy land of Cockayne i would just type smth like

```
@for /F "tokens=2" %%G in (my_preciouss.txt) do @echo %%G > my_preciouss.txt
```

But since the content of some_very_long_line is really long and the maximum length of any command line (or variable) within CMD is just 8191 characters, i do not succeed with this procedure.

For some unlucky reasons I have to do this in cmd. I know how to do it in bash with sed or powershell, but this unfortunately not an option for now.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you use the same tool as you stated you used last time, `FindStr`? In `cmd.exe` try `For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %A In ('FindStr "::" "my_preciouss.txt"') Do @Echo %B`. If it works you could output it to a file.

Comment: How the hell is this not about batch programming? The OP has shown the code that he would use to solve the problem (never mind the bugs), but he correctly diagnosed that batch limitations prevent him from using the technique in his case. He is looking for guidance on how to work around the very real batch programming limitation.

Comment: @Compo, the limitation is still there

Comment: @Max, I'm working only with the information you provided; what method did you use to extract and write the data with `FindStr` initially. Just replicate it, it's the same data after all!

Comment: @Compo, the output of the findst command is bigger than 8191 characters, so when you are trying to put it into a variable %A or %B, nothing happens

Comment: @MaxDr, your question never mentioned or showed it being put into a variable, you only said 'save'. You stated, 'this was created with findstr from a bigger txt file'. So, unelss you've provided incorrect information, this means that `FindStr` has already successfully handled that same string. I am well aware of the restrictions in character length and I never said that `FindStr` would handle the string. I made no statements of fact, I simply asked questions based solely on your information, _neither of which you answered!_

Comment: As far as I know `findstr` -- like (almost) all internal and external `cmd` commands -- cannot handle lines longer than ~ 8190 bytes/characters, so please let us know how your very long line has been created...

Comment: @aschipfl, this is not true

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/findstr-escapes.html "Files specified as a command line argument or via the /F:FILE option have no known line length limit. Searches were successfully run against a 128MB file that did not contain a single <LF>.

Piped data and Redirected input is limited to 8191 bytes per line. This limit is a "feature" of FINDSTR. "

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault, I had something wrong in mind... Anyway, what is the specific criterion to remove the prefix? is it the first space or sequence of spaces, or is it the `::`, or is the prefix always `attribute::`?

Answer (score 1):

Handling very long strings in pure batch scripting is nasty but possible.

The `set /P` command is quite useful for that, because it reads a redirected input file in chunks of 1023 bytes/characters when there is no line-break. The `copy` command features an ASCII mode (`/A`), in which source files are read up to but not including the first end-of-line (EOF) character (also SUB; ASCII 0x1A), truncating everything behind; this can be (mis-)used to safely write strings without trailing line-breaks (opposed to `echo` with a redirected output file).

Here is a commented script that utilises these commands:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem /* Define constants here: */
set "_FILE=%~dp0my_preciouss.txt"      & rem /* (path to the target file) */
set "_DROP=attribute::"                & rem /* (string to strip; everything up to that
                                         rem     is omitted, so maybe `::` was enough?) */
set "_TMP1=%TEMP%\%~n0_1_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem /* (path to a temporary file) */
set "_TMP2=%TEMP%\%~n0_2_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem /* (path to a temporary file) */

rem /* Determine number of chunks of 1023 bytes: */
for %%F in ("%_FILE%") do 2> nul set /A "NUM=%%~zF, NUM/=1023"

rem /* Gather end-of-file (EOL) character by using `copy` in ASCII text mode: */
> nul copy /Y /A nul "%_TMP1%" & for /F "usebackq" %%S in ("%_TMP1%") do set "EOF=%%S"

rem /* Read from the given file: */
< "%_FILE%" (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Read first chunk of 1023 bytes from the file using `set /P` together with
    rem    and input redirection (`<`); remove everything up to the given drop string
    rem    from the chunk and write it plus a trailing EOL to a temporary file: */
    set /P LINE="" && > "!_TMP1!" (
        for /F "tokens=* eol= " %%L in (" !LINE:*%_DROP%=!!EOF!") do (
            endlocal & (echo(%%L) & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
    )
    rem /* Read the remaining file chunk by chunk and append each to the temporary file,
    rem    using `copy` in ASCII mode, in which it treats the EOL (end-of-line) character
    rem    as such and truncates it and everything behind; that way, you can get rid of
    rem    the trailing line-break that the `echo` command appends as it is behind EOL: */
    for /L %%I in (0,1,%NUM%) do (
        set /P LINE="" && (
            > "!_TMP2!" echo(!LINE!!EOF!
            > nul copy /Y /A "!_TMP1!" + "!_TMP2!" "!_TMP1!"
        )
    )
    rem /* Append a final line-break (carriage-return plus line-feed) to the file;
    rem    if you do not need that, remove the whole `echo` command line and replace
    rem    `"!_TMP2!"` by `nul` in the `copy` command line: */
    > "!_TMP2!" echo/
    > nul copy /Y /A "!_TMP1!" + "!_TMP2!" "!_TMP1!" /B
    endlocal
)

rem /* Replace original file and clean up temporary files: */
> nul copy /Y /A "%_TMP1%" "%_FILE%" /B && 2> nul del "%_TMP1%" "%_TMP2%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple interface in Python or C++ (or really any language that allows you to give it command line args) to do what you need, calling it like so:

```
shortfile "my_preciouss.txt"
```

Where `shortfile` is the utility you write above and the filename is (obviously) the file you wish to shorten.

Answer (score 0):

Native batch is really poor for doing text manipulation - as you have discovered.

It is theoretically possible to solve this with "pure" batch and native external commands. The "simplest" would probably be to use CERTUTIL to write out the file as hex. Then scan the hex and write a new hex file containing the values after the first space (hex 20). Then use CERTUTIL to convert back to ASCII. But there is no way I would bother to take that painful approach.

Check out [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a regular expression find/replace utility written as pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any modern Windows machine from XP onward.

Use `jrepl /?help` to see all types of built in help. `jrepl /?options` will give you a quick summary of all available options.

Based on your vague description, I see a couple ways to process the file.

```
call jrepl "^attribute:: " "" /f "my_preciouss.txt" /o -
```

or

```
call jrepl "^.*? +" "" /f "my_preciouss.txt" /o -
```

But I'm sure you can come up with your own solution if you are comfortable with sed.

I suspect you can avoid this cleanup operation entirely if you ditch FINDSTR and use JREPL to generate the correct file in the first place.

Note that CALL will double any quoted `^`, but that will not be a problem with the beginning-of-line anchor, since `^^search` is equivalent to `^search`. But it can cause a problem with something like `[^xyz]`. If executing the command directly on the command line, then you can drop CALL and avoid the issue. But if in a batch script, you can avoid the caret doubling problem by adding the `/xseq` option, and substituting `\c` for `^`.